# Controlling third party threading from native code

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'd like to start off by saying I am in no means an expert in threading, and hence the reason for this question.

I have a home grown abstract logger which schedules calls to logging providers on a `Task.Run` like so:

```
 public void Info(string message, Exception exception)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var p in _providers)
            {
                try
                {
                    p.Info(message, exception);
                }
                catch
                {

                }

            }
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
```

I am now running into a curious scenario where one of my logging providers is using an external library which writes to *cosmos db* and it does this, internally, on an asynchronous basis.

```
 public void Debug<T>(string message, T objectToLog)
    {
        var model = GetLogModel(message, toSerialize: objectToLog);

        _logRepo.Create(model); // << this guys is async

        //var s= Task.Run(async () => await _logRepo.Create(model)).Result;
    }
```

As you can see, by the commented out code, I'm currently trying some funky options to try and get this to run synchronously. I know I can call `.Result` without the secondary task below but that seems to be taboo.

My question is
*How can I make this library code run synchronously without inadvertently causing deadlocks or other phantom problems that tend to be difficult to track down?*

Comment: I assume the logging provider in question is in your hand and you can manipulate it. In this case you can write a decorator for your third party assembly and make sync methods for the async operations. Most libraries have some sort of BeginXXX() and EndXXX() functions or similar. Look out for this operations or some events that you can use to determine if the operation was successfull.

Comment: There are a lot of existing questions about it, hard to pick the one you want.  Find them by googling "c# how to run async code synchronously".